# Configuring CORS

Tags: spring-boot, security, cors

I have REST server written in spring boot and then I have web-server (IIS running on windows, there are only html/css/js and web.config files). Application should run only on local network and I dont know, how to set up CORS.

Web server runs on docmanager.com and REST server runs on docmanager.com:8443, both on the same computer. Problem is, that I needed to setup REST server like this:

```
@Component
 @Order(Ordered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE)
public class CorsConfig implements Filter {

   @Override
    public void init(FilterConfig filterConfig) throws ServletException {

    }

        @Override
        public void doFilter(ServletRequest req, ServletResponse res, FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {
            HttpServletResponse response = (HttpServletResponse) res;
            HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest) req;


            response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
            response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "POST, GET, OPTIONS, DELETE, PUT");
            response.setHeader("Access-Control-Max-Age","3600");
            response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "x-requested-with, authorization, content-type, access-control-alow-origin");

            if("OPTIONS".equalsIgnoreCase(request.getMethod())){
                response.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_OK);
                response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
                response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
                response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "POST, GET, OPTIONS, DELETE, PUT");
                response.setHeader("Access-Control-Max-Age","3600");
                response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "x-requested-with, authorization, content-type, access-control-alow-origin");
            } else {
                chain.doFilter(req, res);
            }

      //      chain.doFilter(new XSSRequestWrapper((HttpServletRequest) request), response);
        }


        @Override
        public void destroy() {

        }
    }
```

When I use instead of Access-Control-Allow-Origin: * -> Acess-Control-Allow-Origin: docmanager.com:443, then it does not work. I am also testing it on the same computer. 
How should I setup this CORS related things? I was using it with "*" during development, but I need to make it ready for distribution, but I dont know how to setup CORS for this local network...
Can I somehow avoid completely setting up CORS with my setup (web server, rest server etc...)?

Thanks for help :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you mentioned your web server is on a different port and REST server on a different port

In this case, CORS will definitely come in picture.

The configuration looks correct.

I think the problem is with domain name which you are setting

```
docmanager.com:443
```

Not sure of this but it should be something like this

```
https://docmanager.com
```

Try to inspect the browser and get the exact value.

**On Side note**

What you are doing is adding a `Filter` and for each request setting header information.

Since you are using `Spring-boot` there is cleaner way of doing it

*With WebMvcConfigurerAdapter*

```
@Configuration
//@EnableWebMvc
public class CorsConfiguration extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter
{
    @Override
    public void addCorsMappings(CorsRegistry registry) {
        registry.addMapping("https://docmanager.com")
                .allowedMethods("GET", "POST");
    }
}
```

*With WebSecurity*

```
@EnableWebSecurity
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.cors().and()
            //other config
    }

    @Bean
    CorsConfigurationSource corsConfigurationSource()
    {
        CorsConfiguration configuration = new CorsConfiguration();
        configuration.setAllowedOrigins(Arrays.asList("https://docmanager.com"));
        configuration.setAllowedMethods(Arrays.asList("GET","POST"));
        UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource source = new UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource();
        source.registerCorsConfiguration("/**", configuration);
        return source;
    }
}
```

More detail [here](https://howtodoinjava.com/spring5/webmvc/spring-mvc-cors-configuration/) and [here](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-cors)

**Edit 1:**

Adding more detail

1 You can add all the methods in array list

2 OPTIONS (pre-flighted requests) are automatically handled by Spring.

Here is quote

> CORS requests (including preflight ones with an OPTIONS method) are
>   automatically dispatched to the various HandlerMappings registered.
>   They handle CORS preflight requests and intercept CORS simple and
>   actual requests thanks to a CorsProcessor implementation
>   (DefaultCorsProcessor by default) in order to add the relevant CORS
>   response headers (like Access-Control-Allow-Origin). CorsConfiguration
>   allows you to specify how the CORS requests should be processed:
>   allowed origins, headers, methods, etc.

More detail on this [here](https://spring.io/blog/2015/06/08/cors-support-in-spring-framework)

Comment: thanks for your answer. I need to use PUT, DELETE, POST and GET. But also - how this is gonna work without OPTIONS? My front-end does not work without allowing OPTIONS (pre-flighted requests...)?

Comment: You can add all methods in Array. Spring will take care of OPTIONS .  Edited.